# How to increase the size of each graph in facet_wrap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-bar

I set up a facet_wrap of graphs depicting each employee's productivity based on the number of points/customer name and separated into the various service types. The ensuing picture below is produced:

Picture of graph: separated by employee name, each column is the customer name listed on the right

[image]

While it's set up the way I want, is there any way to increase the size of each graph for more clarity as the bar columns are pretty clustered (preferably expanding the x-axis)? Here is the code I wrote up below:

```
ggplot(data = rd_may) +
         geom_bar(aes(x = `Service Type`, y = Total_Points, fill = `Customer Name`), stat = "identity", width = 0.4, position = position_dodge(width=0.9)) +
              geom_point(aes(x = `Service Type`, y = Average_Rop*10, group = `Customer Name`), position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
                geom_line(aes(x = `Service Type`, y = Average_Rop*10, group = `Employee Name`)) +
                facet_wrap(~ `Employee Name`, ncol = 3) +
                  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(trans = ~./10, name = 'Pins/Hr')) +
                  scale_x_discrete(guide = guide_axis(n.dodge = 7)) +
     theme(axis.text.y = element_text(color = "#4B92DB"), 
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = "red")) +
                    ylab('# of Pins') +
                      labs(title = "Total Pins vs Average ROP by RD Staff", subtitle = "May Aggregate")
```

Comment: If you resize the plot window, the plots will become larger relative to the legend. If you're in Rstudio, press the "zoom" button and maximize the resulting window

Comment: When you output the plot you can set the size - e.g. `ggsave("plot.png", plot, width = 10, height = 10, units = c("in"))`.

Comment: These two comments exactly.  Text does not scale the same as geoms and your plot area, so if you save with larger size output, all text will appear smaller in comparison, which should get you where you are looking to go.  Otherwise, try setting smaller size legend items and labels using the appropriate `theme()` elements.

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked. mlcyo's method was the one I used